# How to execute a function after another function is complete in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a button that I want to execute two animation functions when clicked but I want to execute the second one only after the first one is complete

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          animate(nodesVisitedInOrder);
          animate(path); // I want to execute this function only after the prev one is complete
        }}
   >
```

I tried to put the second function in a setTimeOut like so, but they are still running at the same time.

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          animate(nodesVisitedInOrder); 
         setTimeout(() => animate(path), 1000);
        }}
   >
```

Here's the animation function:

```
 const animate = (nodes) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const node = nodes[i];
            setTable((prev) => {
            const newArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < prev.grid.length; i++) {
                newArray[i] = prev.grid[i].slice();
            }
            return {
                ...prev,
                grid: newArray.map((items) =>
                items.map((item) => {
                    const { row, col } = item.pos;
                    return row === node.row && col === node.col
                    ? { ...item, isAnimate: !item.isAnimate }
                    : item;
                })
                ),
            };
            });
        }, 10 * i);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the animate function?
There are several ways you can implement this, depending on the animate function implementation.
is the animate function an async function?
does it return anything when completed?
is it a function you wrote or is it from a library?

Comment: So the animate function changes the state of the component, which then rerenders the component thereby changing the className of html elements which the css then styles. Not sure if that makes sense. It's not an async function and tbh I'm not familiar with how async functions work. It doesent return anything:

Comment: Modify `animate` to return a promise and await it.

Comment: maybe something like https://pastebin.com/GsuTKN8L

Comment: @JaromandaX that worked! tysm :)

Comment: @marsalah - added as an answer :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest change to your code is to use promises to determine when the animate has finished

Like so

```
const animate = (nodes) => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        promises.push(
            new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const node = nodes[i];
                    setTable((prev) => {
                        const newArray = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < prev.grid.length; i++) {
                            newArray[i] = prev.grid[i].slice();
                        }
                        const ret = {
                            ...prev,
                            grid: newArray.map((items) =>
                                items.map((item) => {
                                    const { row, col } = item.pos;
                                    return row === node.row && col === node.col
                                        ? { ...item, isAnimate: !item.isAnimate, }
                                        : item;
                                })
                            ),
                        };
                        resolve();
                        return ret;
                    });
                }, 10 * i);
            })
        );
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

And then, your button can use

```
<button
    onClick={() => {
        animate(nodesVisitedInOrder).then(() => animate(path))
    }}
>
```

Comment: Hey I know this is a bit late, but can u tell me why this works, and why not having the whole animate function return a single promise wont work, as I tried this out and It doesent work as both animations happen at the same time.

Comment: so, this doesn't work ... OK ... I don't know why @marsalah

Comment: @marsalah - why have you accepted the answer after saying it doesn't work? That makes no sense

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. The method that you've laid out in your answer does work. But I was curious why one couldnt just return 1 promise from the animation function as a whole rather than having all the SetTimeOuts be their own promises (as I've tried to do this and this doesent work) . I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ahhh, @marsalah, I guess you could just have a Promise that resolves on the last iteration, since that's the one with the longest delay - however, as I don't know what `setTable((prev) => {` does, or even if it's asynchronous or not, I played it safe

Comment: fair enough! thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: I just realised the code has a couple missing `)` !! I guess you sorted that @marsalah